# How to control the sequence of RequestExecutor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint-2013, office365

I had developed an intranet site by using SharePoint Office 365.

In the master page file, There is a menu bar (using List to store the URL and name).

I want to control the "Admin" buttton that the button is visible when they are in 'Admin' group user.

I confirmed that the Check admin right function can work properly.

BUT the checking function is execute after the function to generate menu bar.
so that it cannot get the variable to control the button to show/hide.

How can i execute the check admin right function first ? Thanks

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"></SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
<title>Intranet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../SitePages/Site.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetQueryStringParams(sParam) 
    { 
       var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1); 
       var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'); 
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)  
        { 
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('='); 

            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)  

            {
                return sParameterName[1]; 
            }
        }
    }


    var isAdmin=false;
    var appweburl="https://XXX.sharepoint.com/XXX/";    

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var scriptbase = appweburl+ "/_layouts/15/";
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest1);     
    });


    function execCrossDomainRequest1() {

        var executor1 = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor1.executeAsync(
            {
              url: appweburl + "/_api/web/currentuser",
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandlerCurrentUser,
              error: errorHandler
            }
        );              

        var executor9 = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor9.executeAsync(
            {                               
              url: appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site_TopMenuBar')/items?$orderby=Sort_x0020_Order",
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandler,
              error: errorHandler
            }
        );          

    }

    var currentId;
    function successHandlerCurrentUser(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        currentId=jsonObject.d.Id;

        var executor6 = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor6.executeAsync(
            {
              url: appweburl + "/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetById(77)/Users",    
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandlerGroup,
              error: errorHandler
            }
        );

        $('#username').html(jsonObject.d.Title);
    }

    function successHandlerGroup(data) {

        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var iMember=false;
        //console.log(currentId);

        for (x=0;x<jsonObject.d.results.length;x++){
        //console.log(jsonObject.d.results[x].Id);
            if (jsonObject.d.results[x].Id==currentId){
                iMember=true;
                break;
            }               
        }
            if (iMember==true){
                isAdmin=true;
                //console.log(isAdmin);
                }
                else
                {
                isAdmin=false;
                //console.log(isAdmin);
                }       
    }       

    function successHandler(data) {         
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var announcementsHTML = "";

        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        $("#mainMenuMaster").find("tr").remove();
        row='<tr>';
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].Disabled==false){    
                    if (results[i].Title=='Admin') {
                    //console.log('menu-' + isAdmin);       
                    //as it execute before admin right checking, so that isAdmin always false;
                        if (isAdmin==true){                 
                            row+='<td class="hvr-fade" style="height:25px" align="left"><a  style="color:white; text-decoration: none; margin: 10px;" title="'+results[i].Tooltip+'" href="'+results[i].URL+'">'+results[i].Title +'</a></td>';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row+='<td class="hvr-fade" style="height:25px" align="left"><a  style="color:white; text-decoration: none; margin: 10px;" title="'+results[i].Tooltip+'" href="'+results[i].URL+'">'+results[i].Title +'</a></td>';
                    }

            }
        }
        row+='</tr>';
        $('#mainMenuMaster> tbody:last').append(row);
    }

    function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage);
    }


    function getUserWebPermissionREST() {
        //Permission for admin to show or hide the entries on memory board using ShowOnHomePage Field

        var perm = new SP.BasePermissions();
        perm.set(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb);

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/doesuserhavepermissions(@v)?@v={'High':'" + perm.$4_1.toString() + "', 'Low':'" + perm.$5_1.toString() + "'}",
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var d = data.d.DoesUserHavePermissions;
                if (d === true) {

                    //Show Check Box if Full Control
                }

                else {
                    //hide Check Box

                }
            },

          error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    }       

    function errorHandlerAddItem(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    }



    </script>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>     
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(image/background.png);background-repeat:repeat;font-family:Helvetica, Arial;font-size:10pt">
<form id="form1" runat="server">&nbsp;
<center>
<table style="width:1280px;text-align:center;border:none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>

<!--
<td><img src="../SitePages/image/Logo1280.jpg" style="border:none;width:1280px" /></td>
-->
<td style="font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial; color:#55AAFF; background-image:url(../SitePages/image/Logo1280_182.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;width: 1280px; height:182px;" align="right" valign="bottom">
<b>
Welcome &nbsp;
<span id="username" style="color:#f58320;"/>
</b>
<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf" style="color:black; font-weight:bold">Logout</a>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr><td style="background-color:#100b67;font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt;font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;">
<table id="mainMenuMaster" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border:none">
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:white">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="color:white;background-color:#100b67;font-size:9pt;font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;">
(c) Copyright 2015
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:80px"><td style="background-image: url(image/footerRepeat.png); background-repeat:repeat-x;" align="right"><span id="username"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not know this is right answer or not, but I suggest a way. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){/*checking Authority and determine display attribute*/})`. I think it's gonna work

Comment: thanks. will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Juneyoung.

my solution as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    checkAdminRights();
});

function checkAdminRights() {
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var groupId = 42;   
    var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose" };

    $.ajax({
        url : _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupId + ")/users/getbyid(" + userId + ")",
        contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers : requestHeaders,
        success : userOwner,
        error : userNotOwner
    });
    function userOwner(data, request){
        var userName = data.d.LoginName;
        isAdmin=true;
    }
    function userNotOwner(error) {
        isAdmin=false;
    }       

}
```